# Guest user login issues during AD Connect synchronization from on prem AD to Azure AD

Tags: authentication, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I have synchronized guest users from on premise AD to Azure AD using below reference. 
403 error is seen when user tries to login to new experience view of My Apps and no apps are visible on console.
Please find below screenshots for reference:
[Developer tool logs and 403 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4cjN.png)

In respect to above scenario, can you please help us understand.
1. How to fix Guest user access for My apps in new experience view of My Apps?

References:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/b2b/hybrid-on-premises-to-cloud

Comment: 403 error usually occurs when there is no permission. Please try to [add a guest user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/b2b/add-users-administrator) and invite in your application.

Comment: The above link refers to on-boarding users using Azure portal. While, our requirement is to sync guest users using AD Connect or Custom scripts (PowerShell, graph API). We are not creating Guest users from Azure portal, they are synced from on-premise ADDS.

Comment: Yes, it uses portal to create. But you could eliminate the problem of permission.

Comment: We have already tried using portal and it works fine for Guest users created from Portal. But our use-case is to sync users to AAD from AD using AD Connect. Users which are synced as Guest user as part of this synchronization face 403 error as mentioned above. Our ask is to know other than portal how can we handle this 403 error.

Comment: Hi @KrunalKadam, this is a known issue and the product team is working on this to get fixed.